# PJSIP in xcode not working,Gossip Example code is also not compiling?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I'm here to share my issue with you.I'm working on PJSIP since last 3 days but still not found the solution.
I get to know that in PJSIP api ,i need to wrap clases for making them workable on xcode.
But during R&D i got this link:

https://github.com/chakrit/gossip

Here,everything is wrapped in objective-C ,but this does n't get compiled.It gives me issues of files Missing.
Initially it gave config_site.h is missing,so i i have downloaded PJSIP library from this link:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

and drag n drop the pjsip folder in my project.But still it gives issue.

**So,if anyone have any solution of using pjsip for calling and chatting purpose,please do favour me.**

Comment: any help would be appreciated,please reply

Answer (score -1):

Hi in this link[gossip github](https://github.com/chakrit/gossip)

they proveded some commands to build pjsips, follow these commands

1. First execute the follwing commands in terminal (to clone the gossip source code)

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/chakrit/gossip.git
   cd gossip
   git submodule init
   git submodule update --recursive
   ```
2. to build pjsips execute following commands

   For example, to create a new build for arm64, try the following:

   `$ cd gossip
    $ cd pjsip
    $ ./pjsip arm64
    $ ./pjsip info arm64`

   (Or) to create new fat binaries on your machine, try the following

   `cd gossip
   cd pjsip
   ./pjsip all
   ./pjsip info .`